# Get distingushed name of the AD Logged user from the local computer?

Tags: c#, active-directory, winui, domainservices

Is it possible to get a distinguished name of the logged to AD user from the local computer?
I mean I can retreive user's logged in ad info, as follow:

```
using System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory;
using System.Security.Principal;
 AdFQDN = Domain.GetComputerDomain().Name;
 AdUserName = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

And it works perfectly fine, except I also need a distingushed name of the user in follwoing format:

```
CN=UserName,CN=Users,DC=DOMAIN,DC=com
```

I mean I can generate it from the AdUserName but it gonna be a quite hard coded, and not good practice as once I will move user to different OU, the whole logick will broke. So instead of hard coded generator I would like to have a proper name pulled localy, because anyway current  user will be already logged in to the AD so I think this info should exist localy.

Also I know, that I can request that info via DomainServices lib, but this lib requres to have an opened context, which is also depends on "Distingushed name" so it is kind of infinte loop.

I would be very appreciate you if you could help me resolve this issue.

Thx in advance,
Best regards,
Maks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    var userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, Environment.UserName);

    if (userPrincipal != null)
    {
        return userPrincipal.DistinguishedName;
    }
}
return string.Empty;
```

Hopefully this should get you there.

Comment: Dear Andy, yes your suggestion 100% solved my issue. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's more accurate to use the SID to search

```cs
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

using var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
var sid = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User.Value;
var userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.Sid, sid);
return userPrincipal?.DistinguishedName ?? "";
```